# What is the recommended way to authorize my aws api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have set up a cognito user pool and have attached this to an identity pool.  I wanted to allow only valid users from my user pool to execute my aws api.  I have been reading about authorizing my api but there seems to be a number of ways to do this as follows:

1. Using an IAM role that I can attached to my authorized identity role
2. Using a custom authorizer in the aws api gateway

Based on what I want to do above, is there a recommended way to implement the api authorization?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the API you are calling, uses the user data, I would go with 2. If not, 1 would work as well. However, why do you want to integrate with an identity pool unless supporting federation with Google, Facebook etc.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Comment: thanks.  i ended up using the cognito user pool authentication which is quite straightforward.